# Eclipse progress view stop button listener

Tags: eclipse, addeventlistener, uiprogressview

I develop an eclipse plugin, and I created an progress view which indicates where the work runs. Everything works correctly, but I have a question. When I made this view an stop button appeared on it. But I haven't found any listener to control this. But the best should be that if there is an pause button within the view insted of the stop button. Please give me some idea! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The `Job` where you do the work is given an `IProgressMonitor` when its run method is called.  This progress monitor has an `#isCanceled()` method.  I believe that when you click the stop botton in the progress view, then the `isCanceled` method on your progress monitor should return `true`.